Calculate how many fields $L$ such that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq L \subseteq K$ exist if $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt[3]{5})$.
Calculate how many fields $L$ such that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq L \subseteq K$ exist if $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt[3]{5})$.
It is straightforward to note that we only need to find the fields $L$ such that either $[L:\mathbb{Q}] = 3$ or $[L:\mathbb{Q}] = 9$. Moreover, it is easy to show that:
$(1)$ The fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{3})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{5})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt[3]{5})$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{6}, \sqrt[3]{5})$ have index 9 over $\mathbb{Q}$.
$(2)$ The fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{6})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{10})$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{15})$ have index 3 over $\mathbb{Q}$.
However, I am unsure how to proceed from this point. Could you help me find the remaining fields or guide me on how to complete the solution?

Hints.

Let $j=\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}.$ Then, $K(j)/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, and its Galois group $G$ is the semidirect product of the normal subgroup
$Gal(K(j)/\mathbb{Q}(j))\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^3$
and the subgroup of order $2$ generated by complex conjugation.

The subfields $L$ you are looking for correspond to subgroups of $G$ containing complex conjugation. You probably can count them or determine them all.  It is most likely that these subgroups will have the form $H\rtimes \langle *\rangle,$ (but you will have to prove it first) where $*$ is complex conjugation and $H$ runs through the sets of subgroups of $Gal(K(j)/\mathbb{Q}(j))$, which are easy to determine.

If $d$ is the number of such subgroups, it is probably quicker to determine $d$ obvious subfields of $K$ rather than determine all of the corresponding fixed fields.


